# XSD convert JSON array

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm trying to convert below JSON to XSD, however I was not able to come up with the correct XSD for the array type.

```
{
    "activeIndicator": true,
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "one",
            "bid": "12444",
            "name": "dsdsddd"
        },
        {
            "type": "sss",
            "bid": "322333",
            "name": "sdfsfff"
        },
        {
            "type": "sddssddsd",
            "bid": "4343434",
            "name": "ffdssdddd"
        },
        {
            "type": "rerererer",
            "bid": "5767767",
            "name": "fdsfdffff"
        }
    ],
    "expiryDateIndicator": true
}
```

Below is the XSD I have come up with so far.

```
<xsd:complexType name="EntityType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="bid" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="Response">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="activeIndicator" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="entities">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:list itemType="EntityType"/>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

But above is throwing an *org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: undefined simple type 'EntityType'* when try to compile. curious to know what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item type of a list must be a simple type, not a complex type.

You haven't shown the XML instance that you want to use to represent this JSON data, but I think it's unlikely to make use of list types. I would expect something like

```
<entities>
  <entity>
    <type>x</type>
    <bid>y</bid>
    <name>z</name>
  </entity>
  <entity>
    <type>x</type>
    <bid>y</bid>
    <name>z</name>
  </entity>
</entities>
```

in which case `entities` would be defined as:

```
    <xs:element name="entities">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
               <xs:element name="entity" type="EntityType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```